# Voice recorder for Android

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am looking for a voice recorder for Android that is not visible when recording (= not visible in the nodification bar, in the lock screen, and  notification LED) and records voice in a decently compressed format (mp3, 3gp, etc. even compressed lossless like FLAC).

The native voice recorder application leaves marks pretty much anywhere it can (notification bar, lock screen, etc.).  [Smart Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder&hl=en) is almost perfect but save recordings as .WAV.

If possible, free and works with android 4.4.2.

Comment: see this http://lifehacker.com/5879500/the-best-voice-recording-app-for-android

Comment: @unique_id It's a good list to have.

Comment: If you're still looking, I just stumbled upon [Secret Audio Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.defensivedroidapps.spyc.audio.demo). Last update 9/2014, though.